# What does the error means: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected (SQL: )`

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

On my Amazon RDS Postgresql database connection I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected (SQL: ^sql^)
```

So I try to understand what this error mean. As far as I understood it that my database client has established a database connection that for some reason has been unexpectedly terminated. Is that right?

So I wonder will this error also mean that another error has happened in my database connection that has failed to be captured in client side?

Comment: Look in the server's log file to see what the server thinks happened.  If the connection disappeared, clearly the server can't tell the client what happened, as there is no connection to send a report over.